# When to use Oracle Objects (User Defined Types)?

Tags: oracle, object, oracle11g, user-defined-types

I have a dilemma. Use or not to use Object.
While implementing some validation procedure I realized that below function:

```
function my_table_row_has_not_children (
  p_my_object_id in number
) return varchar2
is
  t_counter number := 0;
begin

  select count(*)
    into t_counter
  from other_table_than_my_object other_obj
  where other_obj.fk_my_object_id = p_my_object_id;

  if t_counter = 0 then
    return 'T';
  else
    return 'F';
  end if;

end;
```

is ideal candidate for object method because it's highly correlated with my_table_row.
It would be also used at least in two different packages.
I would also achieve clearer code.

Anyway I've researched that Oracle Objects are not so popular:
[How widely used are Oracle objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767200/how-widely-used-are-oracle-objects), but Oracle still
develops its, as shows Oracle 12c doc : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjadv.htm#ADOBJ006.

Our application doesn't use too much objects, rather rarely.
So, should I create Object for such case or simply extract the function to more general package and use it in both places.
Can you also give some other arguments to use Oracle Objects?

---

My sample code:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS OBJECT (
  id           NUMBER,
  MEMBER FUNCTION my_table_row_has_not_children RETURN boolean;
/

CREATE TYPE BODY my_type AS
  MEMBER FUNCTION my_table_row_has_not_children RETURN boolean IS
    t_count number := 0;
  BEGIN
    select count(*) into t_count
    from other_table_than_my_object other_obj
    where other_obj.fk_my_object_id = p_my_object_id;

    if t_count > 0 then
      return true;
    else
      return false;
    end if;
  END;
```

Meanwhile I decided to move other two highly correlated functions with that object inside its. Validation pl/sql which uses now that object is much clearer now than before.
I wonder about maintaining such methods but it's separated topic...

After some coding and thinking about that I am pretty sure it was good decision.
More examples appreciated :)

Comment: How would you convert that to an object, and how would you access it? Or is `my_table_row` already an object, in which case your function just becomes a method - which seems the way to go? If it's a normal table row then having a single function instance would make sense to avoid code duplication and reduce maintenance; but for this example wouldn't it be simpler to have a view that outer-joins the tables and has the actual count and/or a T/F flag as extra columns? Depending on how you're using the function that might be considerably more efficient as well.

Comment: I added some code. As it is narrowed context usage I think defined type will be better than view, but thank you for good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I use Object types occasionally for creating XML documents, it's quite handy.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "IPoverEthernet" AS OBJECT (
 "@ethernetIpAddress" VARCHAR2(15),
 "@ethernetSubnetMask" VARCHAR2(15))
/

SELECT XMLTYPE("IPoverEthernet"('10.100.100.20','255.255.255.0')) FROM dual;

returns 
<IPoverEthernet ethernetIpAddress="10.100.100.20" ethernetSubnetMask="255.255.255.0"></IPoverEthernet>
```

Of course, you can create more complex XML elements.